# How to fix Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR in react-native-google-signin?

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I get a problem to use react-native-google-signin (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin), I have followed the instructions base on documentation, but I always get error like this below :

```
Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR
    at createErrorFromErrorData (D:\myProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:152)
    at D:\myProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:104
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (D:\myProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:442)
    at D:\myProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:127
    at MessageQueue.__guard (D:\myProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:343)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (D:\myProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:126)
    at debuggerWorker.js:80
```

this is my script :

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    GoogleSignin.configure();
  }

  signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      console.log(userInfo);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        // user cancelled the login flow
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        // operation (e.g. sign in) is in progress already
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        // play services not available or outdated
      } else {
        // some other error happened
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>App Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="google"
          onPress={this.signIn}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to look for many examples but fail all, please anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you solved the problem....?

Comment: @AbdullaZulqarnain yes, I have solved this problem, for debug , use SHA1 from debug.keystore, you can find this keystore in YOUR_APP/android/app/debug.keystore, and for release use SHA1 from your keystore release, goodluck